# Reliance 3 ac2739 data card not detected in ubuntu 14.4

Tags: networking

I am using reliance 3 ac2739 data card, but not working in Ubuntu 14.4. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Please read solution below 
 read what was my problem carefully at this below link.
[Unable to connect to the internet on a Ubuntu 14.0.4 laptop using zte(reliance cdma) AC2739 USB modem‏](https://askubuntu.com/questions/626207/unable-to-connect-to-the-internet-on-a-ubuntu-14-0-4-laptop-using-ztereliance-c/626681#626681)

I Have the Same usb that u have.
it would be better if u provide system logs. Any Way here is the solution that worked for me. 
**Cause Of Problem**: Multiple modes of modern dongles.

**Solution:**
1.

> gedit /etc/usb_modeswitch.conf

2.add this code to diable usb switching  at the top.

> DisableSwitching=1

3.save it.
4.insert usb again
5.eject usb cdrom by right click eject it 
or using.

> sudo eject /dev/sr1

6.Wait for 5-10 sec(time to detect it as modem)
7.now go to network manager 
8.Reliance network will be listed in network manager connect to it by creating new connection.
You can also installed UI one provided by Reliance if u want let me know.