# Unable to connect to the internet on a Ubuntu 14.0.4 laptop using zte(reliance cdma) AC2739 USB modem‏

Tags: 14.04, network-manager, usb-modem, usb-modeswitch, zte

Many Linux/Ubuntu users face this problem -->(connect to internet using modem zte/etc.....) because modern dongles have USB storage + modem+CD ROM,
usb_modes switch blablabla.......................

**what is my problem?**
--> I am not able**(sometimes able to)** to connect internet using ZTE(Reliance cdma) AC2739 .

How Ubuntu Detect my USB dongle?
Ans : in 3 Ways :

1) do not detect USB device but `lsusb` show the device.

2) detect the device (1 in 10 case after inserting USB) but network manager does not detect it as broadband connection.

3) detect the device(1 in 15 case after inserting USB) and also network manager detect it as broadband connection-----> this is case when I am able to connect to internet.

System logs for all 3 cases:

Common logs (this is what system logs shows every time when I insert USB dongle)

```
'May 20 20:51:19 pcp kernel: [ 2724.187204] usb 3-3: new full-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd<br/>
May 20 20:51:19 pcp kernel: [ 2724.205404] usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=19d2, idProduct=fff1<br/>
May 20 20:51:19 pcp kernel: [ 2724.205415] usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3<br/>
May 20 20:51:19 pcp kernel: [ 2724.205420] usb 3-3: Product: ZTE CDMA Tech<br/>
May 20 20:51:19 pcp kernel: [ 2724.205425] usb 3-3: Manufacturer: ZTE, Incorporated
May 20 20:51:19 pcp kernel: [ 2724.205430] usb 3-3: SerialNumber: 000000000002
May 20 20:51:19 pcp kernel: [ 2724.208710] usb-storage 3-3:1.5: USB Mass Storage device detected
May 20 20:51:19 pcp kernel: [ 2724.208930] scsi14 : usb-storage 3-3:1.5
May 20 20:51:19 pcp mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 10: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3"
May 20 20:51:19 pcp mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 10 was not an MTP device'
```

case 1: (not sowing common logs -->above one)

```
May 20 18:52:15 pcp usb_modeswitch: switch device 19d2:fff5 on 003/003
May 20 18:52:42 pcp kernel: [ 3082.599319] scsi 7:0:0:0: CD-ROM            ZTE      USB Storage FFF1 2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
May 20 18:52:42 pcp kernel: [ 3082.601400] scsi 7:0:0:1: Direct-Access     ZTE      USB Storage FFF1 2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
May 20 18:52:43 pcp kernel: [ 3083.337421] sr1: scsi3-mmc drive: 0x/0x caddy
May 20 18:52:43 pcp kernel: [ 3083.337618] sr 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
May 20 18:52:43 pcp kernel: [ 3083.337689] sr 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
May 20 18:52:43 pcp kernel: [ 3083.338257] sd 7:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
May 20 18:52:43 pcp kernel: [ 3083.346309] sd 7:0:0:1: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
May 20 18:52:43 pcp kernel: [ 3083.386955] systemd-udevd[5293]: Failed to apply ACL on /dev/sr1: No such file or directory
May 20 18:52:43 pcp kernel: [ 3083.386971] systemd-udevd[5293]: Failed to apply ACL on /dev/sr1: No such file or directory
May 20 18:52:43 pcp kernel: [ 3083.391821] systemd-udevd[5293]: Failed to apply ACL on /dev/sr1: No such file or directory
May 20 18:52:43 pcp kernel: [ 3083.391832] systemd-udevd[5293]: Failed to apply ACL on /dev/sr1: No such file or directory
```

case 2 (not sowing common logs -->provided at top)

```
May 20 19:35:52 pcp kernel: [  910.651091] usb 3-3: reset full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
May 20 19:35:52 pcp kernel: [  910.667601] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff8800777e6180
May 20 19:35:52 pcp kernel: [  910.667613] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff8800777e61c0
May 20 19:35:52 pcp kernel: [  910.672647] scsi 12:0:0:0: CD-ROM            ZTE      USB Storage FFF1 2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
May 20 19:35:52 pcp kernel: [  910.674693] scsi 12:0:0:1: Direct-Access     ZTE      USB Storage FFF1 2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
May 20 19:35:52 pcp kernel: [  910.679319] sr1: scsi3-mmc drive: 372x/372x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda 
May 20 19:35:52 pcp kernel: [  910.679996] sr 12:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
May 20 19:35:52 pcp kernel: [  910.681364] sr 12:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
May 20 19:35:52 pcp kernel: [  910.682692] sd 12:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
May 20 19:35:52 pcp kernel: [  910.689527] sd 12:0:0:1: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
May 20 19:35:52 pcp kernel: [  910.789754] sr1: CDROM (ioctl) error, command: Xdread, Read track info 52 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 08 00
May 20 19:35:52 pcp kernel: [  910.789777] sr: Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
May 20 19:35:52 pcp kernel: [  910.789783] sr: Add. Sense: No additional sense information
May 20 19:35:52 pcp kernel: [  911.234442] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 1
May 20 19:35:52 pcp kernel: [  911.247345] ISOFS: changing to secondary root
May 20 19:35:52 pcp udisksd[2223]: Mounted /dev/sr1 at /media/prakash/Reliance on behalf of uid 1000
```

case 3: (not sowing common logs -->provided at top)

```
    May 20 20:51:19 pcp kernel: [ 2724.248971] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial
    May 20 20:51:19 pcp kernel: [ 2724.248989] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
    May 20 20:51:19 pcp kernel: [ 2724.249002] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
   May 20 20:51:19 pcp kernel: [ 2724.264994] usbcore: registered new interface driver option
    May 20 20:51:19 pcp kernel: [ 2724.265650] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for GSM modem (1-port)
    May 20 20:51:19 pcp kernel: [ 2724.265826] option 3-3:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
    May 20 20:51:19 pcp kernel: [ 2724.265979] usb 3-3: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
    May 20 20:51:19 pcp kernel: [ 2724.266042] option 3-3:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
    May 20 20:51:19 pcp kernel: [ 2724.266161] usb 3-3: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
    May 20 20:51:19 pcp kernel: [ 2724.266218] option 3-3:1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
    May 20 20:51:19 pcp kernel: [ 2724.266334] usb 3-3: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
    May 20 20:51:19 pcp kernel: [ 2724.266390] option 3-3:1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
    May 20 20:51:19 pcp kernel: [ 2724.266505] usb 3-3: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB3
    May 20 20:51:19 pcp kernel: [ 2724.266562] option 3-3:1.4: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
    May 20 20:51:19 pcp kernel: [ 2724.266687] usb 3-3: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB4
   May 20 20:51:19 pcp kernel: [ 2724.266757] option 3-3:1.6: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
    May 20 20:51:19 pcp kernel: [ 2724.266885] usb 3-3: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB5
    May 20 20:51:20 pcp ModemManager[720]: <warn>  (ttyUSB5): port attributes not fully set
    May 20 20:51:20 pcp ModemManager[720]: <warn>  (ttyUSB2): port attributes not fully set
    May 20 20:51:20 pcp ModemManager[720]: <warn>  (ttyUSB3): port attributes not fully set
    May 20 20:51:20 pcp ModemManager[720]: <warn>  (ttyUSB1): port attributes not fully set
    May 20 20:51:20 pcp ModemManager[720]: <warn>  (ttyUSB0): port attributes not fully set
    May 20 20:51:20 pcp ModemManager[720]: <warn>  (ttyUSB4): port attributes not fully set

    May 20 20:51:20 pcp usb_modeswitch: switched to 19d2:ffffffff on 003/009
    May 20 20:51:20 pcp kernel: [ 2725.207972] scsi 14:0:0:0: CD-ROM            ZTE      USB Storage FFF1 2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
    May 20 20:51:20 pcp kernel: [ 2725.210011] scsi 14:0:0:1: Direct-Access     ZTE      USB Storage FFF1 2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
   May 20 20:51:21 pcp usb_modeswitch[4855]: usb_modeswitch: switched to 19d2:fff1 on 3/10
    May 20 20:51:21 pcp kernel: [ 2725.888378] sr1: scsi3-mmc drive: 372x/372x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda 
    May 20 20:51:21 pcp kernel: [ 2725.888912] sr 14:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
    May 20 20:51:21 pcp kernel: [ 2725.889419] sr 14:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
    May 20 20:51:21 pcp kernel: [ 2725.893403] sd 14:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
    <br/>May 20 20:51:21 pcp kernel: [ 2725.910131] sd 14:0:0:1: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
    May 20 20:51:21 pcp kernel: [ 2726.006326] sr1: CDROM (ioctl) error, command: Xdread, Read track info 52 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 08 00
    May 20 20:51:21 pcp kernel: [ 2726.006351] sr: Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
    May 20 20:51:21 pcp kernel: [ 2726.006357] sr: Add. Sense: No additional sense information

    May 20 20:51:22 pcp usb_modeswitch[4855]: usb_modeswitch: add device ID 19d2:fff1 to driver option
    May 20 20:51:22 pcp usb_modeswitch[4855]: usb_modeswitch: please report the device ID to the Linux USB developers!

    May 20 20:51:22 pcp kernel: [ 2726.597676] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 1
   May 20 20:51:22 pcp kernel: [ 2726.608596] ISOFS: changing to secondary root
    May 20 20:51:22 pcp udisksd[2228]: Mounted /dev/sr1 at /media/prakash/Reliance on behalf of uid 1000
   May 20 20:51:38 pcp ModemManager[720]: <info>  Creating modem with plugin 'ZTE' and '6' ports
    May 20 20:51:38 pcp ModemManager[720]: <warn>  Could not grab port (tty/ttyUSB4): 'Cannot add port 'tty/ttyUSB4', unhandled serial type'
    May 20 20:51:38 pcp ModemManager[720]: <warn>  Could not grab port (tty/ttyUSB2): 'Cannot add port 'tty/ttyUSB2', unhandled serial type'
    May 20 20:51:38 pcp ModemManager[720]: <warn>  Could not grab port (tty/ttyUSB5): 'Cannot add port 'tty/ttyUSB5', unhandled serial type'
    <br/>May 20 20:51:38 pcp ModemManager[720]: <warn>  (ttyUSB0): port attributes not fully set
    May 20 20:51:38 pcp ModemManager[720]: <info>  Modem for device at '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3' successfully created
    May 20 20:51:39 pcp ModemManager[720]: <warn>  Couldn't load unlock retries: 'Unknown error'
    May 20 20:51:39 pcp ModemManager[720]: <warn>  couldn't load list of Own Numbers: 'Failed to parse NV MDN command result: -17'
    May 20 20:51:39 pcp ModemManager[720]: <warn>  couldn't load current allowed/preferred modes: 'Unknown error'
    <br/>May 20 20:51:39 pcp ModemManager[720]: <info>  Modem: state changed (unknown -> disabled)
    May 20 20:51:39 pcp NetworkManager[784]: <warn> (ttyUSB0): failed to look up interface index
    May 20 20:51:39 pcp NetworkManager[784]: <info> (ttyUSB0): new Broadband device (driver: 'option1' ifindex: 0)
    May 20 20:51:39 pcp NetworkManager[784]: <info> (ttyUSB0): exported as /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2
    May 20 20:51:39 pcp NetworkManager[784]: <info> (ttyUSB0): device state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
    May 20 20:51:39 pcp NetworkManager[784]: <info> (ttyUSB0): deactivating device (reason 'managed') [2]
    May 20 20:51:39 pcp NetworkManager[784]: <info> (ttyUSB0): device state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none') [20 30 0]
```

If anyone want text file of whole log please let me know. This problem is in many USB dongles. If any one can provide any solution to this problem please do it. I am trying from 3 days hope I will get solution now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after analyzing  **System logs** carefully this solution worked for me
**Cause Of Problem**: Multiple modes of modern dongles.

**Solution:**
1.

> gedit /etc/usb_modeswitch.conf

2.add this code to diable usb switching  at the top.

> DisableSwitching=1

3.save it.
4.insert usb again
5.eject usb cdrom by right click eject it 
or using.

> sudo eject /dev/sr1

6.Wait for 5-10 sec(time to detect it as modem)
7.now go to network manager 
8.Reliance network will be listed in network manager connect to it by creating new connection.
7.now go to network manager 
8.Reliance network will be listed in network manager connect to it by 
creating new connection.
that's all
*Reliance provide UI software also*
simply install it using

> sudo ./file name

run it using

> sudo ztemtapp

this is working for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had a pretty similar problem with my ZTE USB modem and it turns out it was getting mounted as a CD unit.

This is how I solve it:

Step 1: Use **lsusb** to verify your usb modem is detected

```
sergiotca@sergiotca-Dell-System-XPS-L502X:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 8086:0189 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c07e Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 19d2:2000 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0408:2fb1 Quanta Computer, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Step 2: Use **dmesg | tail** to know how it has been detected

```
sergiotca@sergiotca-Dell-System-XPS-L502X:~$ dmesg | tail
[ 6136.744009] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: ZTE,Incorporated
[ 6136.744012] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: MF1800ZTED010000
[ 6136.747257] usb-storage 3-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 6136.747504] scsi19 : usb-storage 3-1:1.0
[ 6137.748200] scsi 19:0:0:0: CD-ROM            ZTE      USB SCSI CD-ROM  2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 6137.751676] sr1: scsi-1 drive
[ 6137.752168] sr 19:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
[ 6137.752731] sr 19:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
```

Step 3: Use **usb_modeswitch** to change the mode of your usb modem by "ejecting it" using the **-K** parameter. Use the vendor and product ID from your own modem (**lsusb**)

```
sergiotca@sergiotca-Dell-System-XPS-L502X:~$ sudo usb_modeswitch -v 0x19d2 -p 0x2000 -K
[sudo] password for sergiotca: 
Look for default devices ...
   product ID matched
Found devices in default mode (1)
Access device 010 on bus 003
Current configuration number is 1
Use interface number 0
Use endpoints 0x01 (out) and 0x81 (in)

USB description data (for identification)
-------------------------
Manufacturer: ZTE,Incorporated
     Product: ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM
  Serial No.: MF1800ZTED010000
-------------------------
Sending standard EJECT sequence
Looking for active driver ...
 No active driver found. Detached before or never attached
Set up interface 0
Use endpoint 0x01 for message sending ...
Trying to send message 1 to endpoint 0x01 ...
 OK, message successfully sent
Read the response to message 1 (CSW) ...
 Response successfully read (13 bytes).
Trying to send message 2 to endpoint 0x01 ...
 OK, message successfully sent
Read the response to message 2 (CSW) ...
 Response successfully read (13 bytes).
Reset response endpoint 0x81
Reset message endpoint 0x01
-> Run lsusb to note any changes. Bye!
```

Step 4: Finally use **dmesg | tail** to verify that your usb modem has changed to Direct-Access mode

```
sergiotca@sergiotca-Dell-System-XPS-L502X:~$ dmesg | tail
[ 6874.527436] usb 3-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[ 6874.527700] option 3-1:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[ 6874.527894] usb 3-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[ 6874.528148] option 3-1:1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[ 6874.528305] usb 3-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[ 6874.528510] usb-storage 3-1:1.3: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 6874.528704] scsi20 : usb-storage 3-1:1.3
[ 6875.529082] scsi 20:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ZTE      MMC Storage      2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 6875.532997] sd 20:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 6875.535452] sd 20:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Step 5: Your modem should be detected now by the network manager.